# Export Phabricator tasks to spreadsheet / csv

Tags: export, phabricator

I spent more than 15 minutes on Phabricator to look for the Export to spreadsheet feature without success. I have seen there that [this feature exist](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T257). My goal is to migrate away from Phabricator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to implement [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) and add it into your php config `include_path`.
2. Then you can use the `Export To Excel` on each Maniphest page with the built ind queries and your custom queries.
3. If you need a custom format you need to customize the existing ones. Therefore see files in `./t/phabricator/src/applications/maniphest/export/`

Comment: So if I understand well I just have to add to php the PHPExcel library and the button will appear automatically?

Comment: The button should already be there at the bottom right oft Evers maniphest query page. But it warns you to add the phpexcel into your PHP include path.

Comment: I tried doing this but it did not work, it includes the Paste in PHPExcel in C:/xampp/php and I referenced the folder in PHP.ini and it did not work